doxywizard fails to produce output while doxygen works
Using version 1.12.0 under Ubuntu 24.10, I configured a new project with doxywizard following the docs. I started the executable from command line:
$ ~/mark/doxygen-1.12.0/bin$ ./doxywizard

Other information:
$ ~/mark/doxygen-1.12.0/bin$ ./doxywizard --version:

Doxywizard version: 1.12.0 
(c73f5d30f9e8b1df5ba15a1d064ff2067cbb8267), Qt version: created with 6.2.4, running with 6.6.2

and
$ ~/mark/doxygen-1.12.0/bin ./doxygen -v

1.12.0 (c73f5d30f9e8b1df5ba15a1d064ff2067cbb8267)

since I've downloaded the release from the repository, the doxygen executable are of course not found using which.
Then I configured the project, saved it to enable the "Run doxygen" button, but clicking on it, it just outputs:

*** Failed to run doxygen

without any further explanation.
But running doxygen myconfig.file previously saved leads to correctly generate the documentation.
How to understand why it fails?
I tried to look for log files under /var/log but I found nothing related to doxygen. Searching inside /var/log/syslog leads to a couple of matches but not relevant.
I also searched in the issues on GitHub repository but without luck.


How did you start doxywizard 2. You say "now enabled" did you perform some extra steps after started the doxywizard? 3. what is the result of which doxygen ? 4. What is the result of which doxywizard 5. what is the result of doxygen -v 6. what is the result of doxywizard --version


@albert, thanks, question updated

"since I've downloaded the release from the repository, the doxygen executable are of course not found using which" so it looks like the doxygen executable is not found in your path, so what happens when you add ~/mark/doxygen-1.12.0/bin to the path. (You used for e.g. getting the version already ./doxygen

@albert I found out the solution by myself. I didn't understand the documentation correctly: I have to make install even from the release files, not only when downloading the sources. I thought the wizard would search for doxygen executable in the same directly as it was launched...

If you download the release from github repository you have to type:
sudo make install

even if you have the source files already compiled.
Otherwise the doxywizard does not look in the same directory to find out the doxygen executable. It expectes to find it in the system path.
